# SpringBoot2.7.x Graphql Query did not work

Tags: graphql

first sorry im not good at english

that is my setting, and i call query, SpringBoot is work, query is work
but return nothing, not null, just return nothing in postman

how can i resolve this... :( programming is so hard

```
@Controller
@Transactional
class MemberGraphController (

    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder

        ) {
@QueryMapping
    fun findAllUsers(): List<User> = userRepository.findAll()
}
```

```
type User {
    oid: ID!,
    userId: String!,
    name: String!,
    email: String!
}

type Query {
    findAllUsers: [User],
    findByUserId(userId: String!): User
}
```

```
  graphql:
    graphiql:
      enabled: true
    schema:
      printer:
        enabled: true
      locations: classpath:graphql/**/
      file-extensions: .graphqls, .ggls
```

```
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql")
```

```
2023-11-18 20:49:12.749  INFO 544 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] p6spy                                    :
```